Gender Representation Mismatch in YouTube Analytics API
My API Result
{'kind': 'youtubeAnalytics#resultTable',
 'columnHeaders': [{'name': 'gender',
   'columnType': 'DIMENSION',
   'dataType': 'STRING'},
  {'name': 'viewerPercentage', 'columnType': 'METRIC', 'dataType': 'FLOAT'}],
 'rows': [['female', 0], ['male', 100]]}


Where as the export from YouTube Data Studio I get the respective values:
Excel Output from Data Studio
Call I made:
execute_api_request(
    youtubeAnalytics.reports().query,
    ids='channel=={MY_CHANNEL_ID}',
    startDate='2024-01-01',
    endDate='2024-09-30',
    metrics='viewerPercentage',
    dimensions='gender',
)


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
